# Is there a sql function that can look at ouput and tell if a cell and the cell above it are equal?

Tags: sql, sql-server

it there a function similar to window functions, lead or lag which allow you to take a sql output and compare a cell in one row and then row above it and then give a value based on if they are different

output

```
column1     column2
    7  
    7        same
```

Comment: Why can't you use LEAD and LAG for this?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have cells; It has rows and Columns. A table isn't an Excel Worksheet. Worksheets are stored ordered, tables are not (they are stored in  Heaps). There is no "cell" before or after another "cell" in SQL Server as neither concept exists.

Comment: The question doesn't mention excel anywhere

Comment: I know @FizzBuzz, so why is the OP using the word "Cell"? Cells are a Spreadsheet object; they don't exist in databases.

Comment: SO users trying to help shouldn't really need to guess the functionality in question based on key words

Comment: @FizzBuzz yet you answered with Excel syntax based on a keyword in the question and ignored both the title and the tags.

Comment: That was based on the consensus of other SO Users like @Larnu. Just trying to help another user who is having a hard time wording his question and doesn't want to use SQL functions for this

Comment: I wasn't inferring that the OP is using Excel, just explaining that a worksheet and a table are very different objects. In a worksheet you *can* reference a certain cell, or range, by it's row and column index, i.e.: `B12` and `J2:K12`. That type of functionality doesn't exist in a table in SQL Server. That doesn't mean to say you can't achieve the same results, but to do so you need to turn your dataset into a ordered result set, by use of an `ORDER BY`, and there are a lot of people that have tables where they can't achieve their "insertion order", due to a lack of a column to order by.

Comment: We only have one column here, with the value `7` which doesn't really give us a reliable column to sort by, or a representative example the the OPs real data.

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
   column1,
   CASE WHEN LAG(column1) OVER (ORDER BY column1) =column1 THEN 'same' END AS column2
from [table]
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets -- and this is true of result sets as well, unless they have an `ORDER BY` for the outermost `SELECT`.

There is no "cell above it" or previous row *unless* you specify the ordering criteria.  If you do so, then `LAG()` does what you want:

```
select t.*,
       (case when column1 = lag(column1) over (order by . . . )
             then 'same'
        end) as column2
from t
order by . . .;
```

The `. . .` is for the ordering criterion.  It should be the same in both places.